# How can I draw a ray from the camera in world space?

Tags: opengl

How can I construct a ray from the camera position to where it looks at, in world space. My previous method is draw a line by using two points. The first point is the camera position, and the other is calculated like `camera position + lookdirection`. And then I draw the line using `GL_LINE_LOOP`. But using 'lookdirection' of the camera is wrong, since the result is supposed to be a line that extends from the camera and extends forward.

My method in my program is use the camera position `pos` `(0,10,0)` and face a certain `direction`. Then the endpoint is calculated as `(pos+direction) * 100.0f`, and the starting point is `pos`. I used `glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP,0,2)` to draw the ray. But this produces the wrong result.

What's the correct way to draw a ray from the camera position to where it looks at in world space?

Comment: Welcome to [gamedev.se].  It's not clear what you're asking here.  If your collision system accepts world-space rays for raycasting, why would it make any difference whether you created that ray manually or by projecting from a screen position?

Comment: pretty sure it should be pos+(direction*100.0)

Anyway, could you elaborate what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I pretty sure you should only see 1-pixel dot on screen.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're confused about what constitutes a ray, which is a point with direction. Put another way, it's half of an infinite line. Here's an example:

```
struct ray
{
    vec3 origin;
    vec3 direction;
};
```

Setting a ray to point in the direction of your camera would look like this

```
ray.origin = camera.position;
ray.direction = camera.forward;
```

Since rays extend to infinity in one direction, you'll have to define the segment you want to render:

```
lineSegment.start = ray.origin;
lineSegment.end = ray.origin + ray.direction * length; // a point that is "length" distance from origin
```

All you need to do then is draw a line between those points.